# Sticky Div's need to be eaten

Tags: html, css

I have a question.  I'm creating a single column website that consists of a header, body and footer.  I'm able to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page during re-size, however my question is this.  How do I get the window to "eat" the footer div when re-sizing rather than having it pushed up?  A good example would be ign.com

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
body
{
height: 100%;
background-image: url("..");
}
html
{
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper
{
width: 950px;
min-width: 950px;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
border: 2px solid black;
}
.footer, .push
{
height: 4em;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is the default behavior of block elements.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
​<header></header>
<div></div>
<footer></footer>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
​header, footer {
    height: 5em;
}

div {
    height: 100em;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5txs/)

My advice would be to add more content to your page, or set a larger min-height to the wrapper.

​

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the footer and set certain min-height to the html document.

```
.footer {
margin:1% 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not help.